# PHPExcel saving xlsx to xls, some cells are blank

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have code for converting xls to xlsx via PHPExcel:

```
$objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('file.xlsx');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('new_file.xls');
```

But when I open created xls file some cells are empty.
What could be the problem? 
Thanks!

[Link to download original xlsx file](http://www.m-invest.ru/price/mi-ekb/_m_/929/_p_/file)

Comment: Is there anything in particular about the content of these cells? Are they formulae? or rich text values? or styled in any particular way? or parts of a merge range? or part of an array formula? or a particular charset?

Comment: Knowing which cells aren't being saved might help diagnose the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
you should use one of following as formate type.

1)Excel5 -> file format between Excel Version 95 to 2003
2)Excel2003XML -> file format for Excel 2003
3)Excel2007 -> file format for Excel 2007

and add following line at line no.3 in your code before save file statement.

$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("file.xlsx"); //We can get file reader type automatically using

it generate file as per your requirement.
```

Comment: I not quite understand, where I need use $fileType variable in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I do notice that some of these cells contain references to external files, e.g. cell `A23` contains

```
='[Форма 1-2 от 15.12 ЯНВАРЬ екат.xls]НТТЗМ'!A77
```

Logically, PHPExcel can't simply access that external file (`Форма 1-2 от 15.12 ЯНВАРЬ екат.xls`) to retrieve data; nor can it handle references to external files... the file may not even exist; and if it did, there is a major overhead in loading (recursively) every external file that might be referenced in formulae.

While you haven't indicated which cells might be blank in the newly saved file, it would be my guess that they're the cells that contain these external file references

Comment: Link to Original excel works again. Yes, some cells contain references, but   I havn't this external file and in xlsx file cells is not empty, in xls cells is empty.

Comment: Mark, the cells that are empty are plain text, no formulas, etc.

Comment: Well the cells that I've highlighted certainly aren't plain text, the one I've quoted is a formula referencing a cell in an external file.... can you point me to a specific cell address that contains plain text that is blank when loaded

Comment: Oh, sorry Mark, yes empty cells aren't plain text, it contain references to `[Форма 1-2 от 15.12 ЯНВАРЬ екат.xls]`, but I havn't this file and not understand why xlsx works fine, but xls don't.

Comment: PHPExcel can't reference an external file, but has a fallback behaviour where it picks up on the last calculated result from MS Excel itself; but this value is not always available in Excel files, so it's not a behaviour that's guaranteed, or one that can be controlled by PHPExcel itself